# Запуск бота в телеге python с периодичностью

Tags: python, telegram

У меня есть телеграмм бот, который задает 4 вопроса пользователю и пишет ответы в базу.

Как настроить запуск бота (команда start) с определенной периодичностью? например 5 минут.
Начало скрипта ниже.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
create_db()

spec_list=[]
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess=f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name},напоминаю тебе, что нужно ответить на парочку вопросов!!!'
    aa=bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mess,parse_mode='html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(aa, q1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать отдельный модуль, который с паузой в 5 минут проверял по базе, ответили ли юзеры или нет, и высылал им уведомления. Если не ответил вызывать функцию с напоминалкой, **start** в данном случая нельзя использовать

При вызове start ваш юзер должен добавляться в БД, и состояние ответа на вопросы по умолчанию - FALSE.
После того как ответит на вопросы обновляем эту запись с этим telegram_id в TRUE

Запускать модуль можно посредством crontab например